# Signing into Ubuntu One for Livepatch

Tags: 18.04, security, update-manager, canonical-livepatch

When I hit "Sign In..." on this window to go into my Ubuntu One account, it does nothing. I am expecting a window for my credentials, but nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Are you actually using Ubuntu? There's a Debian logo on your panel...

Comment: Yeah, I am using Ubuntu 18.04, I just liked the Debian logo more :)

Comment: I don't know about that button in 18.04, but you can still follow the official instructions at https://www.ubuntu.com/server/livepatch to sign up and enable it.

Comment: I solved it by command line, with the link you provided, thank you :)

Answer (score 12):

I solved it by going to https://www.ubuntu.com/server/livepatch.

I went to "Generate your credentials" and followed the instructions there.

Then I opened my terminal and typed this two commands:

```
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
sudo canonical-livepatch enable [TOKEN]
```

You get [TOKEN] by following the instructions on "Generate your credentials".

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for the heads-up on the CLI approach!

Comment: I couldn't sign into live-patch as it wouldn't accept my password but I did this and it fixed the problem! This works great, thank you.

Comment: This solution works on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS too. Thanks!