# Liveptach services can't get authorized

Tags: 22.04, patch, canonical-livepatch, ubuntu-advantage, single-sign-on

I can't login into my Ubuntu accounts through gnome-control-center's "Online Accounts" Tab since it is raising error with "Error Connecting Ubuntu Single Sign-On server: \n Something went wrong, please try again"

and when i try to enable livepatch (`ua enable livepatch`) it fails:

```
One moment, checking your subscription first
Stderr: Could not retrieve client information.: GET request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/{...}/info" failed

Stdout:
Unable to enable Livepatch: Failed running command '/snap/bin/canonical-livepatch enable <REDACTED>' [exit(1)]. Message: Could not retrieve client information.: GET request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/{...}/info" failed

Unable to determine current instance-id
```

and when I try to enable livepatch(`canonical-livepatch enable <TOKEN>`)

```
failed to register client: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/{...}" failed
```

and please note that I am running a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (AMD64) based machine.
and please additioanly note that i tried

1. [Canonical livepatch service stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270869/canonical-livepatch-service-stopped-working)
2. [Canonical livepatch failed when I tried to enable token](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264961/canonical-livepatch-failed-when-i-tried-to-enable-token)
3. [Canonical Livepatch internal error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142602/canonical-livepatch-internal-error)
4. [Canonical Livepatch has experienced an internal error, on start up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376275/canonical-livepatch-has-experienced-an-internal-error-on-start-up)
5. [Can't enable Canonical Livepatch on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271580/cant-enable-canonical-livepatch-on-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts)
6. [Signing into Ubuntu One for Livepatch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047839/signing-into-ubuntu-one-for-livepatch)
7. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420465
8. [Can not enable Livepatch service on 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403568/can-not-enable-livepatch-service-on-22-04)
9. [Ubuntu Single Sign-On Account stuck on "Connecting..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069356/ubuntu-single-sign-on-account-stuck-on-connecting)
10. [ubuntu 20.04 cannot login ubuntu Single Sign-On Account "Something went wrong, please try again"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361658/ubuntu-20-04-cannot-login-ubuntu-single-sign-on-account-something-went-wrong-p)

but none of them worked!!

---

### System Specifications

- Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
- Life cycle: LTS
- Architecture: AMD64
- canonical-livepatch: v10.2.3
- ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon: v1.9~22.04.1
- ubuntu-advantage-pro: v27.8~22.04.1
- ubuntu-advantage-tools: v27.8~22.04.1
- Kernel version (`uname -a`): 5.15.0-37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody...
it worked again after trying the recommended commands in my ubuntu forums's question(https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2475854&p=14099828#post14099828)

```
sudo snap run canonical-livepatch disable
sudo snap remove canonical-livepatch
sudo rm /etc/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
sudo systemd-machine-id-setup
sudo dbus-uuidgen --ensure=/etc/machine-id
sudo canonical-livepatch enable [unique token]
sudo snap forget [snapshot ID]
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
sudo snap save
```

Comment: You need to do `sudo snap install canonical-livepatch` before `sudo canonical-livepatch enable <token>`